# Hadoop Hbasee Zookeeper error

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

Hello & thanks for taking the time to look at this issue I am having.

Any help is appreciated as I just started working with hadoop and noSQL...

HBase login:

I start a `hbase shell` in through ssh to a remote host and using hadoop sandbox and then the shell starts normally with few warnings:

```
2015-02-22 23:00:17,892 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: hadoop.native.lib is deprecated. Instead, use io.native.lib.available
HBase Shell; enter 'help<RETURN>' for list of supported commands.
Type "exit<RETURN>" to leave the HBase Shell
Version 0.98.4.2.2.0.0-2041-hadoop2, r18e3e58ae6ca5ef5e9c60e3129a1089a8656f91d, Wed Nov 19 15:10:28 EST 2014

hbase(main):001:0>
```

Then I type the cmd `list`

```
hbase(main):001:0> list
```

and I get the following

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.2.0.0-2041/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.2.0.0-2041/zookeeper/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
```

Then there is a wait of several seconds, which I think the HBase is trying to get a connection through zookeeper.

Then I get the following error:

```
2015-02-22 23:05:53,235 ERROR [main] zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: ZooKeeper exists failed after 4 attempts
2015-02-22 23:05:53,241 WARN  [main] zookeeper.ZKUtil: hconnection-0x51038c1a, quorum=sandbox.hortonworks.com:2181, baseZNode=/hbase-unsecure Unable to set watcher on znode (/hbase-unsecure/hbaseid)
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase-unsecure/hbaseid
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.exists(ZooKeeper.java:1045)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.exists(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.checkExists(ZKUtil.java:481)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKClusterId.readClusterIdZNode(ZKClusterId.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperRegistry.getClusterId(ZooKeeperRegistry.java:106)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.retrieveClusterId(ConnectionManager.java:858)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.<init>(ConnectionManager.java:662)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

    . . . 

    at org.jruby.Main.run(Main.java:208)
    at org.jruby.Main.main(Main.java:188)
2015-02-22 23:05:53,258 ERROR [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher: hconnection-0x51038c1a, quorum=sandbox.hortonworks.com:2181, baseZNode=/hbase-unsecure Received unexpected KeeperException, re-throwing exception
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase-unsecure/hbaseid
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)


    . . .
```

and This error keeps repeating.

Comment: Check zookeeper, regionserver and hmaster are start or not?

Answer (score 0):

I Solved the problem by accessing Ambari at port 8080 and resetting all HBase services. Hopefully this helps someone!